# How to debug a flash component within .Net application

Tags: .net, flash

I write a code similar to that on this link.

http://bojordan.com/log/?p=269&cpage=1#comment-23502

the break points inside Flash events is not working, I think I need to attach the debugger to some Flash process in order hitting those break points, instead of .Net exe.

but when I run the application I don't actually find Flash.exe

Is there a way to make the break points in the event handler works.

Thanks